# Change the default behavior of Double.ToString()

Tags: c#, .net

According to this [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/26etazsy(v=vs.110).aspx#DefaultToString), `Double.ToString()` uses `NumberFormatInfo.CurrentInfo` to format doubles. But CurrentInfo has 2 decimals by default and is read-only so I cant change it. How can I change this default behaviour? (calling the overload of ToString() is not a solution)

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can change `CurrentInfo` for current thread by changing `Threading.Thread.CurrentCulture`.

Also, you're not right saying *`CurrentInfo` has 2 decimals by default*. `CurrentInfo` is set based on current system locale, which means you can get different results depending on machine configuration your program is running at.